# Set Methods in R without Assignment

Tags: r, methods, r-s4

I would like to have some post initialize replacement methods in R that can me called without an assignment operator.

So for example:

I would like to be able to call `setNode(o)` and replace slots in object o without having to call something like like `setnode(o) <- c("foo", "bar")`. The reason I want to do this is because I want there to be some interactivity in these (i.e. `select.list`) without the user of the method having to be aware of the details of the assignment.

Is this possible?

Comment: Perhaps I am not using the sort of OO I really want from R, and rather want closures, http://www.lemnica.com/esotericR/Introducing-Closures/, the more I look into this...

Comment: Another thing along the lines that is throwing me off is that when I set something, I also want to set certain "private" slots. So when I call a method a may want it to alter these private slots

Comment: Or perhaps I want R5: https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/R5/bba2424a052f6a9d8bc893a2dfaf9dc178e14ee6

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand your use case, but... syntax like

```
o <- setNode(o, c("foo", "bar"))
```

will, if you don't go through contortions, follow the usual copy-on-change rules of R and make a copy of `o`, rather than replace slot values in `o`. Replacement methods

```
node(o) <- c("foo", "bar")
```

update `o` in place. I use `node` rather than `setNode`, because the setting is implicit in the use. There is nothing that says that `node<-` has to do anything related to the object structure, for instance

```
setClass("Node", representation(n="integer", value="character"),
         prototype=prototype(n=0L))
setGeneric("node<-", function(x, ..., value) standardGeneric("node<-"))
setReplaceMethod("node", "Node", function(x, ..., value) {
    x@n <- x@n + 1L
    x@value <- toupper(value)
    x
})
```

and then

```
> o <- new("Node")
> o
An object of class "Node"
Slot "n":
[1] 0

Slot "value":
character(0)

> node(o) <- c("foo", "bar")
> o
An object of class "Node"
Slot "n":
[1] 1

Slot "value":
[1] "FOO" "BAR"
```

I'm not sure how this relates to your desire "I want there to be some interactivity"; you could write code that had a more call-like syntax, as

```
> do.call("node<-", list(x=o, value=c("foo", "bar")))
An object of class "Node"
Slot "n":
[1] 2

Slot "value":
[1] "FOO" "BAR"
```

but this isn't doing anything different from `node(o) <- ...`.

Choose a reference class (these are build on top of S4, so S4-isms like `setOldClass` apply here) if that is appropriate for the content of the class, not for the interface provided. A data base connection, for example, might be appropriate for a reference class, because there is just a single entity on disk that you are interacting with; mostly, using reference classes will confuse your R users expecting copy-on-change semantics.

Comment: I think I do want reference classes as it looks like how I want this all to work. But now I seem a little stuck where I was using S3 in S4 -- on how to include a RODBC object as a field in a reference class. It seems to return `Error in inherits(channel, "RODBC")" object '.self.' not found`

Comment: Ignore my previous comment, my R session got jacked somehow, wasn't recognizing changes I made to the method.